# use a typescript module/class in the browser and in the server (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, requirejs, typescript

How would I use the same typescript class or module in a client side javascript file and in a server side node.js file?

I found a solution [here](http://srackham.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/building-heterogeneous-typescript-libraries/#comment-13021) where you manually create the `exports` variable instead of using TypeScript's `export` keyword but then you lose the type information for the class when you include it in node.js with the `require` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast what comes out of the `require` function since you know what it's going to be.

```
module Lib {
    export class Alpha {
        bravo: number = 1;
    }
}

// meanwhile back at the ranch
var _lib = <Lib> require("Lib");
var a = new _lib.Alpha();
```